# Find first available node in Nested set model mysql

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data, nested-set-model

i'm new to nested set model
and trying to find the first available node in a tree starting from top to bottom and left to right. each parent node can have 3 child node and i have to find the next available free node.

Table mem
fields m_id,lft,rgt
so far i'm only able to find the depth. like i said i'm new don't know the path ahead

```
SELECT node.m_id,node.lft,node.rgt, (COUNT(parent.m_id) - 1) AS depth
```

FROM mem AS node, mem AS parent WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
GROUP BY node.m_id ORDER BY depth,node.lft;

Comment: Elaborate your question and what have you did so far..??